# What is the best way for keep running state of activity(or app) on android platform?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, status

I gonna find out the way to start my app's main activty from service when the main activity is not forground running. For example in the case the activity is destroyed while executing for crash, need to start activity again. I 'd like to create one service for it to check my activity's running status. if not running my activity my service would start the main activity again so always my activiy keep running status except to be finished by user. What is the best way? Kindly recommend me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your activity have multiple instance, you can add an static variable such as  `static int activeInstance = 0;` or place it in your `SharedPreference` and increase it every time an instance of the activity is called.

If you are sure that the activity can only have on instance running at a time 
you can place `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` inside that activity in the `Manifest.xml` file. You can read in more detail here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Hope that help :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this way is not allowed in case the app would be crashed for some reason.